# Typescript Sequelize create data with keys linked to data in a transaction

Tags: sql, database, typescript, postgresql, sequelize.js

I'm strugling with something that maybe is pretty simple.
I'm using a postgrès SQL with sequelize and typescript.

what I'm trying to do is to create two things and one as Reference on the other but if the creation of one fail then I don't want to commit anythigs.

This is my code where I'm trying to create someone and assign hime some shoes.

```sql
CREATE TABLE User
(
  id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  firstname TEXT,
  lastName TEXT
);

CREATE TABLE Shoes
(
  id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  size INTEGER NOT NULL,
  idUser BIGINT REFERENCES User(id) NOT NULL
);
```

```js
async function operations() {
  const t = await sequelize.transaction();
  try {
    await User.create({
      firstName: 'Bart',
      lastName: 'Simpson'
    }, { transaction: t });

    await Shoes.create({
      idUser: // here I want the id of my futur new creation (bart simpson)
      size: 43
    }, { transaction: t });
    await t.commit();

  } catch (error) {
    await t.rollback();
  }
}

operations.then(() => {/*do something*/})
```

the thing is, I don't know how to get the futur Id of my new user and if I'm putting something hard like 1 if the database is empty or if I get the latest id user and I'm adding 1 then I get an error `violates foreign key constraint`.
I think it's because the user isn't existing in the database but it exist in the transaction.

If someone could help me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fact sending a transaction in a get can also return the value that will be created in the transaction so just need to use get and send the exact same transaction inside the methode